# Temp directory using virtualized path on some computers

Tags: c#, silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-oob, protected-mode

In my Silverlight application I'm using regular SaveFileDialog for prompt user to save some file.

The problem is that on some Windows 7 computers,  if user use IE in protected mode, and try to save to for example on desktop, path for saving ends up like this:

```
C:\Users\<user>\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized\C\Users\<user>\Desktop
```

Does anybody know where I can find flag or value indicating that this path will be used instead of regular one on windows?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using Path.GetTempPath Method?

Comment: Do you run your application in "Out of Browser"-Mode?

Comment: assuming that the Path will always look like this when IE is in Protection-Mode you could try detecing if IE is in ProtectionMode via Interop and this Method [IEIsProtectedModeProcess] for more Info check out this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18866/A-Developer-s-Survival-Guide-to-IE-Protected-Mode#whenispmon (unfortunately this is all C++)

Comment: @Kokulan that is method that I'm using

Comment: @Jehof yes, I have elevated privileges, it is configured properly

Comment: @sine I can try but not sure it will solve my problem because it doesn't happen on my machine with similar conditions, so I guess something else is involved in this 'virtualized' paths

Answer (score 6):

So after a bit of research I´m afraid there is no Flag or Value which Indicates a Virtualized Path...

I know it´s a little bit russian but assuming that this is static

> \Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized\

You could do something like this to check if the Path points to the Virtualized Folder

```
public static bool IsPathVirtualized(string path)
{
        bool isVirtualized = false;
        string pathToVirtualizedUserFolder = Path.Combine
        (
            Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData + 
            @"Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized\"
        );

        if(path.StartsWith(pathToVirtualizedUserFolder))
        {
            isVirtualized = true;
        }
        return isVirtualized;
}
```

Comment: thanks, similar thing I do and it works but I was looking for better solution, don't feel comfortable with string compare...